# How to remap keys using xkb/symbols/us file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have dropped some water on my keyboard and only one key is not working which is the DOWN key. I want now to use some other keys such as right Alt or menu key between right-Alt and right-Ctrl keys as I do not use them very often. I have open the us file in ...xkb/sybmols/us file, however, I am very confused and could not find the Up, Down, Left and Right keys. Can anyone help me to remap the Down key to the menu key on the keyboard? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can easily done via **xmodmap**

```
xmodmap -pke | grep _
```

helps you to know the keycode of your right-hand keys
Then you can assign <kbd>Down</kbd> on choosed key by the command

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 134 = Down Super_R Down Super_R'
```

e.g. for right <kbd>Win</kbd>
To autoload key remaping you can add the command into `$HOME/.xinitrc` or `$HOME/.xsessionrc`